# Javascript not pulling value from form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
userName = Global.getComponent('centerRegion').UserName.getValue();
```

That code pops up with the error

```
 {"browserEvent":"'Global.getComponent(...).UserName' is null or not an object","button":-1,"ctrlKey":false,"xy":[0,0]}
```

When I run it on this form:

```
Using Form As New WebControls.Forms.Form
                With Form
                    .ID = "Test"
                    .ItemName = "connector"
                    With .Toolbar
                        .UseDefaultButtons = False
                        .AddButton(Forms.FormToolbar.ButtonType.Save)
                        .AddButton(Forms.FormToolbar.ButtonType.Cancel)
                        .AddButton("Test Connection", "testConnection", "icon-button-testconnection", , "Test")
                    End With

                    With .CenterRegion
                        .Id = "centerRegion"
                        With .AddFieldSet("Activate Service")
                            .Id = "activate"
                            .LabelWidth = 0
                            Dim cb As New Forms.Control("IsActive", "", "", Model.IsActive, Forms.Control.ControlType.CheckBox)
                            cb.BoxLabel = "Activate Service"
                            .AddControl(cb)
                        End With

                        With .AddFieldSet("Connection Parameters")
                            .Id = "params"
                            .LabelWidth = 150
                            .AddControl(New Forms.Control("UserName", "", "User Name", Model.UserName, Forms.Control.ControlType.TextField))
                            .AddControl(New Forms.Control("Password", "", "Password", Model.Password, Forms.Control.ControlType.Password))
                            .AddControl(New Forms.Control("LoginUrl", "", "URL", Model.LoginUrl))
                        End With
                    End With
                    Response.Write(.ToString)
                End With
            End Using
```

Everything shows up and saves correctly from the form on the screen, so the value IS there, but I think my Javascript is wrong to pull it.

Edit:

Generated HTML:

```
xtype:'fieldset'
,title:'Connection Parameters'
,id:'params',autoHeight:true
,titleCollapse:true
,border:true
,collapsible:false
,labelWidth:139
,anchor:'100%'
,items:[
{xtype:'textfield',validationEvent:'blur',enableKeyEvents:true,anchor:'100%',value:'IDWSSample',fieldLabel:'User Name',itemId:'UserName',name:'UserName',allowDecimals:false,decimalPrecision:0,validator:function(value){var isCustomValid = true;if (this.ux_isInitialized == true) {isCustomValid = function(value){if (value.match(/<[a-zA-Z!\/]{1}/)) return 'If using the "<" character, it must not be followed by "!" or "/" or any letter.';if (value.match(/.*&#.*/)) return 'If using the "&" character, it must not be followed by "#".';return true;}(value);if (typeof(isCustomValid) == 'string') return isCustomValid;}if (isCustomValid == null) isCustomValid = true;return isCustomValid;}}
,
{xtype:'textfield',validationEvent:'blur',enableKeyEvents:true,anchor:'100%',value:'TcYg7m*a',fieldLabel:'Password',itemId:'Password',name:'Password',allowDecimals:false,decimalPrecision:0,inputType:'password'
}
,
{xtype:'textfield',validationEvent:'blur',enableKeyEvents:true,anchor:'100%',value:'http://sample.idws.syndication.kbb.com/VehicleInformationService2008R2.svc?wsdl',fieldLabel:'URL',itemId:'LoginUrl',name:'LoginUrl',allowDecimals:false,decimalPrecision:0,validator:function(value){var isCustomValid = true;if (this.ux_isInitialized == true) {isCustomValid = function(value){if (value.match(/<[a-zA-Z!\/]{1}/)) return 'If using the "<" character, it must not be followed by "!" or "/" or any letter.';if (value.match(/.*&#.*/)) return 'If using the "&" character, it must not be followed by "#".';return true;}(value);if (typeof(isCustomValid) == 'string') return isCustomValid;}if (isCustomValid == null) isCustomValid = true;return isCustomValid;}}
,
{xtype:'combo_transform',validationEvent:'blur',enableKeyEvents:true,anchor:'100%',fieldLabel:'Market Value',id:'ddlMarketValues',itemId:'ddlMarketValues',name:'ddlMarketValues',allowDecimals:false,decimalPrecision:0,id:'EXT_ddlMarketValues'
,el:null
,typeAhead:true
,triggerAction:'all'
,transform:'ddlMarketValues'
,forceSelection:true
,selectOnFocus:true
,lazyRender:true
,resizable:true
,editable:false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the Global.getComponents method is from, but my guess is you have a typo there OR you are not properly accessing the field value.  Try finding the field with regular javascript or even easier with jQuery.

try:

```
var userName = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
```

or with jQuery:

```
var userName = $("#UserName").val();
```

...assuming 'centerRegion' and 'UserName' are id values of elements on your page.

If you're not using jQuery, then you can try the asp.net way:

```
var userName = $find('UserName','centerRegion').value;
```

Comment: When I try the $find, it says $find is not defined. When I try the first suggestion, I get this error "document.getElementById("UserName") is null"

Comment: Make sure you have a ScriptManager object in your aspx page so you can use $find.  null from document.getElementById means "UserName" isn't the actual id value.  It's probably something like "ctl00_UserName". You can access it by injecting the control's ClientID value into the script of the page in server-side code.

Comment: @Bears thanks for the correction.

@Scott - can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: @Scott, not sure what that is, but it's not HTML.  Looks like part of a js object?  Open the page in your browser and view the source to get what's sent to the browser.

Comment: @Scott: that's generated JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: I'm going to give you the correct answer. The document.getElementById ended up working out of nowhere. I built and refreshed and did everything I could before, and nothing worked, but all of a sudden it started to. Don't know why but good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

View the resulting source code and check the name being generated by ASP.NET for centerRegion. Depending on your version of ASP.NET, there may be automatically-generated suffixes added to the name.

If that is the case, update the name to match that being generated and see if this fixes it.